# Problems parsing binary data

Tags: python, parsing, numpy, binary

From a simulation tool I get a binary file containing some measurement points. What I need to do is: parse the measurement values and store them in a list.

According to the documentation of the tool, the data structure of the file looks like this:

```
First 16 bytes are always the same:

Bytes   0 - 7   char[8]     Header
Byte    8       u. char     Version
Byte    9       u. char     Byte-order (0 for little endian)
Bytes   10 - 11 u. short    Record size
Bytes   12 - 15 char[4]     Reserved

The quantities are following: (for example one double and one float):

Bytes   16 - 23 double      Value of quantity one
Bytes   24 - 27 float       Value of quantity two

Bytes   28 - 35 double      Next value of quantity one
Bytes   36 - 39 float       Next value of quantity two
```

I also know, that the encoding is little endian.

In my usecase there are two quantities but both of them are floats.

My code so far looks like this:

```
def parse(self, filePath):
    infoFilePath = filePath+ '.info'
    quantityList = self.getQuantityList(infoFilePath)

    blockSize = 0
    for quantity in quantityList:
        blockSize += quantity.bytes

    with open(filePath, 'r') as ergFile:
        # read the first 16 bytes, as they are not needed now
        ergFile.read(16)

        # now read the rest of the file block wise
        block = ergFile.read(blockSize)
        while len(block) == blockSize:
            for q in quantityList:
                q.values.append(np.fromstring(block[:q.bytes], q.dataType)[0])
                block = block[q.bytes:]
            block = ergFile.read(blockSize)

    return quantityList
```

QuantityList comes from a previous function and contains the quantity structure. Each quantity has a name, dataType, lenOfBytes called bytes and a prepared list for the values called values.

So in my usecase there are two quantities with:

```
dataType = "<f"
bytes = 4
values=[]
```

After the parse function has finished I plot the first quantity with `matplotlib`. As you can see from the attached Images something went wrong during the parsing.

My parsed values:
[image: My parsed values]

The reference:
[image: The reference]

But I am not able to find my fault.

Comment: Did you create your own test dataset to determine if this is a data or a program problem?

Comment: Yes, the reference was created by me. The binary file is correct.

Comment: Do you think its about the data types? The docu tells me, that the floats are 32 bit and the doubles are 64 bit values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve my problem this morning.

The solution couldnt be any easier.

I changed

```
...
with open(ergFilePath, 'r') as ergFile:
...
```

to:

```
...
with open(ergFilePath, 'rb') as ergFile:
...
```

Notice the change from 'r' to 'rb' as mode.

The python docu made Things clear for me:

> Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append 'b' to the mode
>   value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.
>   (Appending 'b' is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and
>   text files differently, where it serves as documentation.)

So the final parsed values look like this:

[Final values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZD7w.png)